# Please explain to me named.stats file

Tags: dns, bind, bind9

I don't quite understand BIND9's statistics file named.stats. Couple of things:

1.) +++ Statistics Dump +++ (1453303803) - what does it mean? Is it when the file was created? And One and half billion - are those seconds counting from 1970? Is there a more human-friendly way to see it?

2.) Below that we've got some statistics. But it's totally unclear to me what's the starting point? Is it from the first installation of BIND9 on my particular system and its first run OR maybe from certain point in the past OR perhaps from the time of last restart?

Answer (score 1):

The statistics dump begins with the line +++ Statistics Dump +++
(973798949), where the number in parentheses is a standard
Unix-style timestamp, measured as seconds since January 1, 1970.

Answer (score 0):

The long sequence of number is the Unix Epoch time, frequently called Epoch.

Unix epoch time represents numbers of seconds since January 1, 1970.

To translate that epoch number into a readable date from the command line (CLI), execute:

```
date -d @1453303803
```

## Use Of Epoch Time

Keep in mind that when you see an epoch number, make note of the operating system that the logger reported on because MacOS X uses a different starting date for their own Unix epoch time.  Other applications cooked their own brand of start date for an epoch number as well.

There are several other kinds of epoch times as well.  More on this [here](https://currentmillis.com/)

### Bind9 Stats Unix Epoch

The epoch time given in first liner of the Bind9 statistics output represents the time that the statistics dump was made (source code: https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/blob/main/bin/named/statschannel.c#L3906 )

### When did all that started?

All that statistics collection started when the `named` process started.

Caveat: Keep in mind, some distros may kill the named daemon and start a new one when executing `service named restart` hence your duration time may differ.

Note: Those using `systemctl restart bind9.service` will not face its daemon being killed off and actually restarted.

## What Each Line Means

Finally, for the details as to what each line means, this [details](https://docs.freebsd.org/doc/8.0-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/bind9/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#statistics_counters) will help you further.